# Figure as part of a paragraph

Tags: floats, paragraphs

I have two paragraphs and one figure.
I want to place the figure as part of the first paragraph.
I want this order: paragraph1 with the figure than paragraph2

```
\paragraph{P1}
text
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Chart_Q1_Branch}
  \caption{Chart1}\label{fig_Q1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\paragraph{P2}
```

Latex result is like this:
P1,P2,figure
What I want is P1 with figure, P2

How could I force latex to do that, with the use of default libraries?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Using the package `float` the `H` floating specifier will be available. This will place the float exactly where it is in the text. You may also want to search for "wrap figure". What do you mean by "default libraries"? You do not want to load any packages?

Comment: For my thesis, I'm using a template which I shouldn't/can't change

Comment: but thx anyway!

Comment: If you can't load packages please modify your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) including all the packages you have in your template. This will help us to avoid guessing.

Answer (score 3):

The poor man's solution is to place the Figure code earlier in your .tex file so that it appears earlier, before paragraph 2 has started.

Another possibility is to place a "*\FloatBarrier*" before the start of paragraph 2, which can be found in the package *placeins*: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/placeins

Comment: Though this is sometimes helpful, keep in mind that FloatBarriers may cause pages that do not look nice.

Comment: @Michael as practically every solution with floats without the possibility to float.

Comment: @masu: Thats right. I just wanted to mention it, since I ran into this error myself. After adding text this didn't look nice anymore. It took a while until I accepted that its the best to not (or at least only rarely) do this by hand.

Comment: @Michael it was totally right to mention it, that's why got the +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Next option would be to add

```
 \clearpage
```

after the figure, it will put them in the right order I guess, but on the more pages (depends on the the size of the paragraphs).